# Multiple Angular JS apps

Tags: angularjs, angular-nvd3

I have implemented two Angular NVD3 Apps for viewing 2 graphs on my html page. I read I could implement both by doing it with ng-modules instead of ng-app, but somehow it is not working. Could You help me?

```
<div ng-modules="temperatureChart" ng-controller="temperatureCtrl">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
    <br><a href="http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/" target="_blank" style="float: right;">See more</a>
</div>
<div ng-modules="heatcounterChart" ng-controller="heatingCtrl">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
    <br><a href="http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/" target="_blank" style="float: right;">See more</a>
</div>
```

That is how I tried it, but it is not working.

Comment: What is `ng-modules`?

Comment: " I read I could implement both by doing it with ng-modules instead of ng-app".  **where** did you read this?  This doesn't seem to be something that is common knowledge....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use 2 angular apps on your page, you need to **not** use `ng-app` to bootstrap your app.  Instead, you should defer bootstrapping via a script that sits on the main wrapper for the 2 apps.  After you have loaded both your apps, scripts, etc. then you can use `angular.bootstrap('document', <ng dependencies array>)`.

You may have trouble in providing the proper sequence of dependencies for both your apps in that you might have race conditions, circular dependencies, etc.  More on manually bootstrapping - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

First you can only have one ng-app on your page at a time.
Second there is no "ng-modules" directive (as far as i know of). The directive you are looking for is "ng-app"

If you have multiple modules, add a new module to your code, that depends on all of these. This new module will then go into your ng-app.

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp",["temperatureChart","heatcounterChart"]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">...
```